# Lotus notes: Create a view with selected senders/receivers

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I would like to create a view in Lotus Notes that displays only the emails sent and received from a select email recipients.

I tried this solutions but it's not working:
https://superuser.com/questions/917406/lotus-notes-client-how-to-create-an-inbox-view-of-only-selected-senders

I also tried creating a view with search formula by adding the following on the search box when creating the view "gmail.com" no quotation marks, but the view just shows all emails even those that don't have anything to do with the domain name gmail.com

Comment: The solution given to the SuperUser question is accurate. What exactly did you do to implement it? Give us the exact steps, and tell us exactly what you expected, and exactly what happened.

Comment: I created a view in Lotus Notes, gave a name to the view, selected "By Formula" in the Selection conditions, typed in the same formula given in the superuser question and only changed the emails example: SELECT From = "sender@domain.com"  - this view only displayed the Meeting Invitation acceptance emails from the recipient. The other formulas SELECT @Contains( @Lowercase( From ; "tim" ) | @Contains( @Lowercase( From ; "tom" ) and this other one SELECT @Contains( @Lowercase( From ; "tim" : "tom" : "paul" ) did not show any email at all - of course I changed the names to the ones I need.

Comment: Did you check the properties of one of the mails that did not show in the view (Alt + Enter, Second Tab, Scroll down to from)? Only if that matches "sender@domain.com" then it will be shown. If it e.g. sais "Sender" <sender@domain.com>, then your view will not show the mails. Just use `@Contains( From; "sender@domain.com" )` to fix that issue...